# Connect iPad 5th Gen to Keyboard

Tags: piano, keyboard, garage-band

I have a Yamaha PSR i455 keyboard and I'd like to connect it to my iPad so I can play the yamaha to input the MIDI data into Garageband. I have an aux cord (3mm jack on both sides) but its too small for the keyboard port. I've seen 3mm to 6mm adaptors on Amazon but I'd like to know if it'll allow me to connect to garageband. I've been able to connect and input midi to my laptop through the printer cable, but I'd like to be able to connect it to my iPad too.
[image: the ports in the Yamaha i455]

Comment: Hi docwho029. One of the criteria on this site for questions is that they show some effort at solving the problem yourself. A simple Google search for "piano to ipad" finds many results that may provide the answer you need. If you've already tried that, please indicate it in your question with some comments on why those answers didn't work.

Comment: Just that you know, some older Yamaha keyboards use non-standard USB MIDI protocol. There's a driver to use them on Windows and Mac, but not iOS.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I thought I'd get more general answers if I left my question vague. Should I make a new post or edit this one?

Comment: As far as my earlier comment goes, your recent edit is perfect. No need to open a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

The "Lightning to USB Camera Adapter" can be used as a USB/MIDI input. I verified it works with Garage Band on the iPad Mini (5th generation, circa 2019 and first generation, circa 2012).

Comment: Oh, thanks! Do you know if the headphone jack will work as a line in for MIDI data? The lightning to USB adaptors i saw on amazon are a little over my budget, so I was looking for a way to use an aux cord(3mm on both sides) which connects the headphone jack of the iPad to a cheap 6mm adaptor which connects to the keyboard?

Comment: @docwho029 One important point: MIDI is computer data, not analog audio data. You can't use an audio jack to transmit MIDI. (Also, you're trying to get data _out_ of the keyboard and _into_ the iPad.) You'll need to use the USB out of the keyboard, and you'll need a cable that connects that to the lightning (data) input of the iPad.

Comment: Chances are you already have a USB-to-lightning cable; it's probably what you use to charge the tablet. If you don't, they shouldn't cost more than about $30USD (often much less).

Comment: the cable doesn't work because my keyboard has a USB-B as MIDI out, and the standard USB port is just for flash drives and importing styles and instruments to the keybiard, and not for exporting MIDI. I guess I'll just buy the lightning to USB adaptor and use my USB-B to Standard USB cable to connect the two devices. Thanks!